# How can I get a list of dimensions from a crossfilter instance?

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

The title basically says it all. I would like to be able to get the list of existing dimensions on a crossfilter instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. You need to keep track of the dimensions you create. [Universe](https://github.com/crossfilter/universe) is working on creating a wrapper that will do this sort of thing for you, in addition to providing a query language.